# sort multilevel array php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
array(
    array(
            id: 4,
            name: car,
            pid: 0
        ),
        array(
            id: 5,
            name: lights,
            pid: 4
        ),
        array(
            id: 6,
            name: fog,
            pid: 5
        )
    ),
    array(
        array(
            id: 1,
            name: bike,
            pid: 0
        ),
        array(
            id: 2,
            name: wheel,
            pid: 1
        ),
        array(
            id: 3,
            name: tire,
            pid: 2
        )
    ),
    array(
            id: 7,
            name: car,
            pid: 0
        ),
        array(
            id: 8,
            name: lights,
            pid: 7
        ),
        array(
            id: 9,
            name: brake,
            pid: 8
        )
    ),
    array(
            id: 10,
            name: car,
            pid: 0
        ),
        array(
            id: 11,
            name: engine,
            pid: 10
        )
    ),
)
```

These multidimesnional array represent the specifications of a car. In a table, it looks like:

```
| car -> lights -> fog |
| bike -> wheel -> tire |
| car -> lights -> brake |
| car -> engine |
```

And now I would like to sort the array, for each level on name. So first, sort on the first column, than sort on the second column etc...

Our sorted array should look like:

```
| bike -> wheel -> tire |
| car -> engine |
| car -> lights -> brake |
| car -> lights -> fog |
```

Using `usort` I can sort on the first column:

```
usort($characteristics, function($a, $b){
    return $a[0]['name'] > $b[0]['name'];
});
```

But offcourse this only affects the first column and in this case, the array looks like:

```
| bike -> wheel -> tire |
| car -> lights -> fog |
| car -> lights -> brake |
| car -> engine |
```

It is also possible to have different lengths (like the engine, that has 2 values, and the bike, which has 3). Normally the length varies between 1 and 5.

I rather wouldn't use too much for/foreach loops, because that would slow my program too much. Also sorry for the long question, but I couldn't find a shorter way to explain my problem.

I hope someone can give me e simple clean solution.

Comment: check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: I knew that function, but I can't really figure out which arguments I should pass to it to sort my array...

Comment: Well if the names of the two element you compare in your user-defined comparison function are the same – then compare the next two attributes that matter … etc. & so on …

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
$arr =
    array(
        array(
            array(
                "id"   => 4,
                "name" => "car",
                "pid"  => 0
            ),
            array(
                "id"   => 5,
                "name" => "lights",
                "pid"  => 4
            ),
            array(
                "id"   => 6,
                "name" => "fog",
                "pid"  => 5
            )
        ),
        array(
            array(
                "id"   => 1,
                "name" => "bike",
                "pid"  => 0
            ),
            array(
                "id"   => 2,
                "name" => "wheel",
                "pid"  => 1
            ),
            array(
                "id"   => 3,
                "name" => "tire",
                "pid"  => 2
            )
        ),
        array(
            array(
                "id"   => 7,
                "name" => "car",
                "pid"  => 0
            ),
            array(
                "id"   => 8,
                "name" => "lights",
                "pid"  => 7
            ),
            array(
                "id"   => 9,
                "name" => "brake",
                "pid"  => 8
            )
        ),
        array(
            array(
                "id"   => 10,
                "name" => "car",
                "pid"  => 0
            ),
            array(
                "id"   => 11,
                "name" => "engine",
                "pid"  => 10
            )
        )
    );

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    foreach ($arr[$i] as $a) {
        foreach($a as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 'name') {
                $newArr[$i][] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}

usort($newArr, function($a, $b) {
    return $a[0] > $b[0];
});

echo "<pre>", print_r($newArr), "</pre>";
```

Comment: Not exactly.. It does a perfect job sorting the names, but I lose the additional info (id, pid, etc..) and it nests 3 loops in eachother, which works with these example data, but not with my data (that is much larger)

Comment: Mention these details in your OP?